# Configure listen_addresses automatically in custom installation

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-11, listener

I have included Postgres in a custom installer for a Windows application. I do not use the installer binary, but extract the Postgres [zip archive](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries) for installation and then run `initdb` from a batch script.

After installation, the db cluster should accept connections from everywhere. Currently my installation routine

1. modifies pg_hba.conf
2. creates a firewall rule

**Problem:** I don't know how make the installation routine configure `postgresql.conf` so that `listen_addresses` is set to the right value:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Currently this has to be done manually. I didn't find a parameter in `initdb` that does this.

**Question:** Is there any way to automate the installation process so that `listen_addresses` is configured as needed? Can this be done using `initdb`?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to append:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

to `postgresql.conf` after running `initdb`. As the last occurrence overrides earlier ones, this would even apply if the default entry were commented out.

Db cluster has to be restarted/[reloaded](https://www.heatware.net/databases/postgresql-reload-config-without-restarting/) after  that.